# Where is the \ifciteibid macro defined?

Tags: biblatex, biber

Is there a macro for `ifciteibid` and other tests used in biblatex citation style customisation ? Where can I find them ? Are they easy to redefine ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: All of these commands are documented in the [`biblatex` documentation](https://texdoc.org/pkg/biblatex). There are a number of tests relating to the ibid tracker described in §4.6.2.

Comment: What is exactly a tracker ?

Comment: It's the general name that `biblatex` uses to refer to the code that "tracks" the use of citations so that terms like *ibid* and *op cit*, etc. can be used correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn) points out [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584287/where-is-the-ifciteibid-macro-defined#comment1468753_584287), the citation trackers like `\ifciteibid` are documented in the `biblatex` manual. The tests like `\ifciteibid` etc. are documented in §4.6.2 *Stand-alone Tests*, the corresponding options that control some of the behaviour of those tests are explained in §3.1.2.3 *[Preamble Options > ] Internal*.

The implementation of a test like `\ifciteibid` consists of several parts, all (or most) of which can be found in `biblatex.sty`.

The first part is the implementation of the test itself ([ll. 2924-2953 in `biblatex.sty` of v3.16](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L2924-L2953)). For `\ifciteibid` the following definitions are used and will be switched according to the preamble option.

```
% {<true>}{<false>}
\def\blx@ifciteibid@global{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\blx@imc@iffieldequals{entrykey}\blx@lastkey@text}
    {\@secondoftwo}}

\def\blx@ifciteibid@context{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
       {\blx@imc@iffieldequals{entrykey}\blx@lastkey@foot}
       {\blx@imc@iffieldequals{entrykey}\blx@lastkey@text}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}

\def\blx@ifciteibid@strict{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\blx@ifcitesingle
       {\blx@ifciteibid@global}
       {\@secondoftwo}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}

\def\blx@ifciteibid@constrict{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\blx@ifcitesingle
       {\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
          {\blx@ifmpfncheck
             {\blx@imc@iffieldequals{entrykey}\blx@lastkey@foot}
             {\@secondoftwo}}
          {\blx@imc@iffieldequals{entrykey}\blx@lastkey@text}}
       {\@secondoftwo}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}
```

The second bit of the implementation is the citation tracking itself ([ll. 11227-11263 in `biblatex.sty` of v3.16](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L11227-L11263)). For `ibid` we have

```
% ibidem tracker
\def\blx@ibidtracker@global{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\global\let\blx@lastkey@text\abx@field@entrykey}
    {}}

\def\blx@ibidtracker@context{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
       {\global\let\blx@lastkey@foot\abx@field@entrykey}
       {\global\let\blx@lastkey@text\abx@field@entrykey}}
    {}}

\def\blx@ibidtracker@strict{%
  \blx@ifcitesingle
    {\blx@ibidtracker@global}
    {\blx@ibidreset@global}}%

\def\blx@ibidtracker@constrict{%
  \blx@ifcitesingle
    {\blx@mpfnsave
     \blx@ibidtracker@context}
    {\blx@ibidreset@context}}%

\def\blx@ibidreset@force{%
  \global\undef\blx@lastkey@text
  \global\undef\blx@lastkey@foot
  \blx@mpfnreset}

\def\blx@ibidreset@global{%
  \global\undef\blx@lastkey@text}

\def\blx@ibidreset@context{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\blx@mpfnreset
     \global\undef\blx@lastkey@foot}
    {\global\undef\blx@lastkey@text}}
```

again, which of those definitions is used depends on the preamble settings.

Specifically, the preamble option selecting the exact behaviour of the test is implemented as follows ([ll. 14844-14871 in `biblatex.sty` of v3.16](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L14844-L14871))

```
\DeclareBiblatexOption{global,type,entry}[string]{ibidtracker}[true]{%
  \ifcsdef{blx@opt@ibidtracker@#1}
    {\csuse{blx@opt@ibidtracker@#1}}
    {\blx@err@invopt{ibidtracker=#1}{}}}
\def\blx@opt@ibidtracker@true{%
  \let\blx@imc@ifciteibid\blx@ifciteibid@global
  \let\blx@ibidtracker\blx@ibidtracker@global
  \let\blx@ibidreset\blx@ibidreset@global
  \booltrue{citetracker}}
\def\blx@opt@ibidtracker@false{%
  \let\blx@imc@ifciteibid\@secondoftwo
  \let\blx@ibidtracker\relax
  \let\blx@ibidreset\relax}
\def\blx@opt@ibidtracker@context{%
  \let\blx@imc@ifciteibid\blx@ifciteibid@context
  \let\blx@ibidtracker\blx@ibidtracker@context
  \let\blx@ibidreset\blx@ibidreset@context
  \booltrue{citetracker}}
\def\blx@opt@ibidtracker@strict{%
  \let\blx@imc@ifciteibid\blx@ifciteibid@strict
  \let\blx@ibidtracker\blx@ibidtracker@strict
  \let\blx@ibidreset\blx@ibidreset@global
  \booltrue{citetracker}}
\def\blx@opt@ibidtracker@constrict{%
  \let\blx@imc@ifciteibid\blx@ifciteibid@constrict
  \let\blx@ibidtracker\blx@ibidtracker@constrict
  \let\blx@ibidreset\blx@ibidreset@context
  \booltrue{citetracker}}
```

The rough idea is the same in all of those tests: The command `\blx@ibidtracker` (which is defined to be one of the `\blx@ibidtracker@...` depending on the option) saves the entry key of the current citation in a helper macro. `\blx@imc@ifciteibid` (the internal name of `\ifciteibid`) can then compare the entry key in the helper macro to the key of the entry that is currently being processed. Depending on the settings `biblatex` may distinguish between footnote and in-text citations and may try to suppress potentially ambiguous uses of 'ibid.' if one of cite calls mentioned several sources at once.